# Finding the gradient with respect to a matrix in the context of a dynamical system

Tags: multivariable-calculus, dynamical-systems, gradient-descent

I have a simple dynamical system where the vectors $\mathbf{x}$, $\mathbf{z}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ evolve over time $t$ as follows:

$\large \mathbf{\hat{x}}_{t} \leftarrow \mathbf{x}_{t-1} + V\cdot\mathbf{b}_t + W_{t-1} \cdot\mathbf{s}_{t-1}$

$\large \mathbf{s}_{t} \leftarrow \mathbf{1}_{\{\hat{x}^{(i)}_{t} \geq 2z^{(i)}_{t-1}\}}$

$\large  \mathbf{x}_{t} \leftarrow \mathbf{\hat{x}}_{t} - 2\mathbf{z}_{t-1} \odot \mathbf{s}_{t}$

$\large  \mathbf{z}_{t} \leftarrow \mathbf{z}_{t-1} + \lambda(\mathbf{x}_{t} - \mathbf{z}_{t-1})$

$\large  W_{t} \leftarrow W_{t-1} - \gamma(\mathbf{x}_{t} - \mathbf{z}_{t-1})\mathbf{s'}_{t-1}$

$\mathbf{1}$ represents the indicator function; $\odot$ represents the elementwise multiplication; and prime ($'$) represents the transpose operation. Subscripts $t$ are time steps, superscripts $i$ are vector elements.

At each time step $t$, this system is supposed to represent a set of $N$ neurons that are responding to an input $V\cdot \mathbf{b}_t$, where $V$ is a matrix of constants. Neurons $x^{(i)}$, $i \in \{1, 2, ..., N\},$ evolve in a two-step process ($\hat{x}^{(i)}$ then $x^{(i)}$). In addition to their previous value and input from $\mathbf{b}$, neurons receive input from neurons that "spiked" at the previous iteration, where spiking means that their $\hat{x}^{(i)}$ exceeded a variable "threshold" $2z^{(i)}$, which itself updates over time. Neurons that spiked at time $t$ are indicated in a vector $\mathbf{s}_t$, and these are multiplied by a square "weight" matrix $W$ which is also updated over time.

---

I am trying to show that the update rules for $W$ and $\mathbf{z}$ are effectively performing gradient descent on the sum of squares loss function $E_t = (\mathbf{x}_{t}- \mathbf{z}_{t-1})^T(\mathbf{x}_{t} - \mathbf{z}_{t-1})$. To do that, I will need to show that:

$\large \nabla_\mathbf{z} E = \mathbf{z}_{t-1} - \mathbf{x}_{t}$

$\large \nabla_W E = (\mathbf{x}_{t} - \mathbf{z}_{t-1})\cdot \mathbf{s'}_{t-1}$

It is easy to show this for the former, but I don't know how to find the gradient of $E$ with respect to $W$. Does it turn out to be the value above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$E_t = (\mathbf{x}_{t}- \mathbf{z}_{t-1})^T(\mathbf{x}_{t} - \mathbf{z}_{t-1})$

Computing the differential of it yields the following:\begin{eqnarray}
dE_t 
&=& 2 (\mathbf{x}_{t}- \mathbf{z}_{t-1}): d\mathbf{x}_{t} \\
&=& 2 (\mathbf{x}_{t}- \mathbf{z}_{t-1}): d\mathbf{\hat{x}}_{t} \\
&=& 2 (\mathbf{x}_{t}- \mathbf{z}_{t-1}): (d \mathbf{W}_{t-1})\mathbf{s}_{t-1} \\
&=& 2 (\mathbf{x}_{t}- \mathbf{z}_{t-1})\mathbf{s}_{t-1}^T: (d \mathbf{W}_{t-1})
\end{eqnarray}
The colon operator denotes the Frobenius inner product.

This gives the gradient
$$
\frac{\partial E_t}{\partial \mathbf{W}_{t-1}}
= 2 (\mathbf{x}_{t}- \mathbf{z}_{t-1})\mathbf{s}_{t-1}^T
$$